# React : detect collision between 2 components

Tags: reactjs

I begin in React by trying to devellop a little game.

A component player can move on a map. It's position is dispatch to the store like that [posx,posy] on every move (Keydown event).

A component Monster is displayed many times on the map. Each component auto-move with a setInterval. The position of each Monster is [posx, posy]. The monsters position is in state of this component.

I would like to check colission between player and each monster when player is moving.

I successed to do that by dispatching monsters position in store, but...
I have 10 monsters, each move is in SetInverval 300ms, so it's 10 dispatch every 300ms and the game is really slow and not optimised.

Is there any other solution to do that ? Without dispatching Monsters positions to the store ?

If you need to see some code, let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You sure can play with react to build a game. But keep in mind that there are tools way more efficient for that. React really isn't for game development. You want to built a chess game or similar? Great. But complex physics, collision detection, this can become pretty junky. Take a look at `Phaser`, or even `P5.js`.

Comment: @Dupocas Yes you're right, but it's just to testing react with someting much fun that ToDoList :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-games-with-react-redux-and-svg-part-1/)

Comment: @Dupocas I will, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of independent timer use single timer to re-calculate game state. `requestAnimationFrame()` might help:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(step);

function step() {
  // detect collisions and update game state here
}
```

Comment: I already have a unique setInterval in parent component, but result is the same.
I'll check requestAnimationFrame
Thanks !

Comment: the thing is to not dispatch several actions, but just dispatch one for re-render

Comment: I tried requestAnimationFrame but the problem still the same.

Many store dispatch (on each move)

Comment: I know what you mean but I don't know how to do that, it's my problem.
I just begin react and I think I do this in the wrong way